# What order are processors called when passed into add_xpath() or add_value()?

Tags: python, scrapy

When using Scrapy, in which order are processors called when passed into an add_value or add_xpath() call like so:

```
...
foo_loader.add_xpath('title', '//title/text', TakeFirst(), Join(), etc etc)
...
```

Judging by this example in the Scrapy docs:'

```
>>> loader.get_value(u'name: foo', TakeFirst(), unicode.upper, re='name: (.+)')
'FOO`
```

I'd assume that they're called left to right, with TakeFirst() acting as the input processor, and unicode.upper as the output processor, and if there happen to be more than two processors for whatever reason, they're called one after the other left to right.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are called left to right.

`add_xpath` eventually calls `get_value`, which contains the following:

```
get_value(self, value, *processors, **kw):
    [...]
    for proc in processors:
        [...]
        value = proc(value)
    return value
```

The full ItemLoader source code is available here:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/loader/__init__.py